# Fetch member by id with the guild id discord js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

how to get a member by id I can provide the guild id tho

For the moment I have this but `cache` is not found

```js
const guild = client.guilds.fetch("gid");
console.log(await guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === "mid"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't fully resolved the promise of `guild`. Consequently your code is ran as `<promise pending>.members...`

This can be fixed by surrounding the promise in `()`

```js
(await guild).members.cache.find(member => member.id === "mid");
```

However, I would recommend `await`ing guild immediately on assignment.

```js
const guild = await client.guilds.fetch("gid");

console.log(guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === "mid"));
```

Furthermore, wrap your async code in a try/catch to catch any errors and use `cache.get()`

```js
try {
   const guild = await client.guilds.fetch("gid");
 
   console.log(guild.members.cache.get("mid"));
} catch (err) {
   console.error(err);
}
```

Keep in mind you may need to fetch the member if they are uncached.